# Can't change default port of a service (apache2 & postfix)

Tags: networking, server, apache2, postfix

When trying to set up a server I stumbled upon a terrible problem: I can't seem to change a service's default port. I have tried to change Apache2's & postfix's default port and all I get (with telnet [IP] [PORT], even within my own network) is trying [my IP here].

In apache2 I made it listen to port 7631 when that didn't work I made it listen to 7632 and of course I changed the virtual host config accordingly.

With postfix I changed the line in master.cf from

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

to

```
1698      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

after that didn't work I reverted it and just added the last line at the end making it listen to port 25 and 1698.

I already looked if it was actually listening:

```
  #  netstat -tanp|grep 1698
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1698            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2325/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::1698                 :::*                    LISTEN      2325/master
```

It seems it is, but when connecting to my internal IP it just hangs on trying [IP].

Of course I also restarted the service's and when I use the default port (80 or 25) it work's just fine.

Previously I could use apache2 fine on port 7631 but when I installed iRedMail (a package also including postfix) it didn't work anymore.

Does anyone know how to solve this, or has any clues due to what causes it?

Thanks in advance,

Gijs

Note: I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-31-generic i686).